# How can I complete delete changes made by WPMU DEV plugin after uninstall?

Tags: wordpress, wpmu

I've installed and deleted (using plugin delete btn in plugins page) the WPMU DEV plugin but its changes in loading the website are still active.
How can I completely delete the changes applied to the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately "deleting" the changes performed by 1 plugin can be or not revertible by uninstalling the plugin. If you have removed it and they are still there you should then revert the database from before those changes where made unfortunately.